# How to add a gap between a rect() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, rect

This may sound confusing, but I need to know how to insert a gap between a rect() in Javascript.

For example: I have a rect() that spans the full width of the screen. I want to put a 100px gap in the center of that rect() so that another rect() could go through the gap when animated.

Below is some example code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawBar() {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(0, (canvas.height/2)-50, canvas.width, 100);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#F1F100";
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.closePath();
}

drawBar();
```

```css
 * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Game</title>
 
 <style>
     * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
    canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto;
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<script src="gameJS.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I added some code Berkay

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hk62yqjL/1/)?

Comment: Although that's not exactly what I want, that definitely gave me an idea on how to do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Didn't understand well, so tried to give you a way. Glad to hear that it worked :)